# What is technology for Azure Data Factory pipeline to Login certain URL

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am working with Azure Data Factory pipe line as below.

1. Pipeline activity Logins to address by webapi in post. (200 or 400)
2. Pipeline activity connects to address by webapi to get json data.

To achieve above. I believe pipe line has 2 activities of 1 and 2 above. 
Result of 1 can be either 200 or 400. (200: to 2/ 400: error)

How Can activity 1 detect 400 error?
Do i need to implement .net CustomActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below ADF's built-in capabilities can fulfill your need:

- **HTTP connector** in copy activity to retrieve data from a web endpoint and copy to any supported sink data store (ADF v1 and v2): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http
- **Web activity** to invoke api request (ADF v2 only): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity
- **IfCondition activity** to do branching (ADF v2 only): not yet well documented but you can get a sense from the SDK reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.ifconditionactivity?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Thanks Linda.
I reached to the knowledge that Data Factory ver1 is not capable for ifCondition or flow control but version 2.